# Ubuntu 18.04 screen sharing is off, but I can VNC... weird?

Tags: 18.04, vnc, vino, desktop-sharing

I can connect to Ubuntu 18.04LTS via TigerVNC / `vino-server`.
And when in a VNC session, I open *Settings* -> *Sharing* and I see *Screen Sharing* is *Off*.

[image]

**Does it make sense?**
I thought it should be *On* to be able to VNC.